# WOW.js + Query Loader 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with [**WOW.js**](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW) and [**Query Loader 2**](http://gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/).

The reason I use Query Loader 2 is because I am using masonry.js (masonry.desandro.com/) to align my portfolio "pinterest-like" and usually the page loads fast, but **SOMETIMES** when I test it in incognito mode in Chrome to see how it will behave for users who open the page for the first time, it takes some time and until the page is loaded, all animations are executed with preloader screen.

So, I would like to achieve that wow.js animations are executed after Query Loader 2 finishes loading.

Here is my [live demo](http://raumfuerkunsttherapie.de/squared_pixel/)

I have execution code for QueryLoader2 in main.js:

```
/* Query Loader 2 */
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        backgroundColor: "#3f4134",
        percentage: true,
        deepSearch: true,
        barHeight: 0,
        completeAnimation: "fade"
    });
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise WOW.js within the `onLoadComplete` callback:

```
/* Query Loader 2 */
$("body").queryLoader2({
    backgroundColor: "#3f4134",
    percentage: true,
    deepSearch: true,
    barHeight: 0,
    completeAnimation: "fade",
    onLoadComplete: function() {
        new WOW().init();
    }
});
```