# query Loader 2 + Wow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For some reason, in my page the Wow.js is not waiting the query loader to complete before starting their animations, can anyone see why?

I have tried using

```
onLoadComplete: function() { new WOW().init(); } });
```

as I saw in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651944/wow-js-query-loader-2), but is not working for me.

[Here](http://fdamaso.com/apresentacao/site/)'s the link of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `onLoadcomlete` to `onComplete` .. 
Here's the full working code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    new QueryLoader2(document.querySelector("body"), {
        barColor: "#000",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 1,
        minimumTime: 200,
        fadeOutTime: 1000,
        onComplete: function () {
            // wow.js
            new WOW().init();
        }
    });
});
```