# Jquery preloader & wow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

I am using the [wow.js plugin & a jquery preload tutorial](http://w3lessons.info/2013/07/18/jquery-preloader/).

The preloader works fine but when it has preloaded the elements on the page, the wow.js animation is already over. I want to edit my code so after that everything is preloaded the animations will start.

I have read this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651944/wow-js-query-loader-2)  but it didn't work for my code.

**My code:**

```
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    // will first fade out the loading animation
    jQuery("#status").fadeOut();

    // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
    jQuery("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");          
})
```

It would be great if anyone would help me, 
Thank you!

Comment: if you used pre-loader than used PaceJs Library it's Automatically handle loading on page load and Ajax Request and very easy so  both are not conflict to gather.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to implement wow js with your custom pre-load code.

```
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
jQuery(window).load(function() {
// will first fade out the loading animation
jQuery("#status").fadeOut();

// will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
jQuery("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");

// Here will be the WoW Js implementation.   
setTimeout(function(){new WOW().init();}, 1000);          
})
```